# Angular formatting Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Coming from a jQuery/PHP background, I'd typically do this using a static method that takes the input and returns it formatted.

With this date: `2014-09-27 03:15:42`

How can I, in AngularJS, format this to show `Sept 27, 2014` aka medium date?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date I've read over these docs., but it seems it only takes timestamps.

What's the best practice for this?

Angular Code with datetimes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions | filter:search">
    <td>{{transaction.created_at}}</td>
    <td>You {{transaction.type}} to {{transaction.to_id}}</td>
    <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to format `transaction.created_at`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create a custom filter to turn it into a date object then use date after so once you've done that you'll end up with {{transaction.created_at | convertToDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}} for example

See http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6743/

```
myApp.filter('convertToDate', function() {
    return function(str){
        return new Date(str);
    };
});
```

Comment: Take a look at fiddle above

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h06mvz9t/)**

[**1**] To implicitly convert the given date inside the controller using the **[`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)** service.

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.mediumDate = $filter('date')(new Date('2014-09-27 03:15:42'), 'mediumDate');
})
```

*HTML*

```
This is set in the controller: {{mediumDate}}
```

[**2**] Use a custom service to convert the given string date format to a date object and then use **[date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** to achieve the medium date format.

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
.filter('toDate', function() {
    return function(stringDate) {
        return new Date(stringDate);
    };
});
```

*HTML*

```
This is set on the view: {{'2014-09-27 03:15:42' | toDate | date: 'mediumDate'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving transactions I would create a field `created_at_timestamp` since **this transaction date will not change overtime**. This way I can reuse it without having to convert it to a `Date` object every time I want to use it.

This logic should be away from the controller so I would put it in a service. Something like that:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.factory('TransactionsService', function() {
  // fetched transactions
  var transactions = [
    {
      created_at: '2014-09-27 03:15:42',
      type: 'someType',
      to_id: 'x',
      amount: 20 
    },
  {
      created_at: '2013-02-15 14:41:02',
      type: 'someType2',
      to_id: 'y',
      amount: 30 
    }
  ];

  var get = function () {
    return transactions.map(function (v) {
      v.created_at_timestamp = new Date(v.created_at);
      return v;
    });
  };

  return {
    get: get
  };
});

app.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, TransactionsService) {
    $scope.transactions = TransactionsService.get();
});
```

Also your view expression to show the date is:

```
{{transaction.created_at_timestamp | date }}
```

[**See this working demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qfwxF)